I have not taken a single day off in an year. Is it healthy? What should I do?
I am freelancer since last 2-3 years. Last year was horrible for me and I was out of work for ~8 months because of poor job market. I started a new project in September.
Right now, I am working on a pretty high paying job (for my skillset). I don't get paid days off as a freelancer so I can't convince myself to take a day off because 1 day of income is too much.
But, I work regular 40 hours/week with no overtime. If I need to travel, I plan it on weekend. If I have a festival, I work on weekend instead to catch up the missing work.
Is it healthy? How do I decide when to start taking more days off?

That's very unlikely to be healthy and it's equally unlikely to be about Freelancing, unless you can show how staff aren't affected the same way… can you?

No it is not healthy. To give you some perspective, in Poland if you are employed on a regular contract, your employer is obligated by law to let you go on a full, uninterrupted 2-week vacation every year. And if you don't do that by yourself, your employer is forced to put you on leave whether you like it or not.
The problem with the health is that everything is OK until it's not. Your organism needs to rest and regenerate after prolonged periods of working. You really don't want to wake up some day and discover some serious issue with your health, which possibly may force you to stop working for prolonged period of time, not only two weeks usually associated with standard vacation time.
You seem to fell into the similar trap I did. I have a sole proprietorship (a single-person company) and most of the time I work for the same customer. When I was switching from contract to this form of cooperation, I thought that since now I will be able to earn more, I will save money for these two weeks, when I'll be on vacation and I won't get paid.
Guess what, when these two week comes, I'm really struggling to stop working, because I'm painfully aware about the money I'm losing. But luckily, I still have enough will to go on vacation; also my wife works too and her salary helps even things up a little.
However I've noticed that in contrast to the time I was working on contract I stopped taking as many days off as I once did. In Poland if you work 10 years (or study and then work 2 years), you are entitled to 26 days of paid leave per year (unused days accumulates to the next year, but you must reclaim them until September). I had a habit of taking a single or two days off every two-three months, just to have some extra time to rest, breathe or even do some things that I needed otherwise, but which were not work. This helped me a lot to avoid burnout and fatigue from prolonged work periods.
So long story short: Yes, it hurts not to work, because you are aware that you don't earn money. But also it is definitely not healthy not to take any breaks in your work.
My suggestion would be to plan a single 2-week (or maybe two 1-week, it may be easier in the beginning) vacations in a year in advance, prepare properly for that period of time and then rest with clear conscience. Planning ahead (way ahead) will let you get used to the idea that you will not be earning money at that time and also prepare accordingly financially.

Thank you. What you wrote applies 100% to me. I will try to follow it :)

Protip: If you have to ask if it's healthy, it usually isn't.
As your own boss, you can choose to work as much or as little as you want. You will need to set boundaries, and setup your pricing model as such. If you want to work 40 hours per week for 5 days a week, then how much do you need to afford those two days off per week? Add that into the quote.
For example, using $100 per day as a round number. That'd be $500 per 5 day work period. If you expand that out to 7 days, it becomes $71.43 per day for 7 days, but only working 5 days.
If you are required to be working 7 days a week for a project, then either time management is the issue, or the project needs more people. We (as humans) are not expecting to work 7 days a week for long periods of time. Our bodies and minds need breaks, or we break.
If you don't make time to rest, your body will make time for it (and take a lot longer to recover).

The basic problem is that this project will end at some point. If you have not taken the time off to do the marketing needed to get the next project, you will be having to start then.
For many people, they need to take at least one day a week for marketing efforts. Trying to do the needed marketing while working many hours is exhausting. (I tried. I got exhausted.)


"Is it ("40 hours/week") healthy? How do I decide when to start taking more days off?

I can't offer medical advice but I can tell you that in North America people usually work 8 hours a day 5 days a week, some for 4 days each 10 hours long; if you don't work over 35 hours a week it's often considered part time.
Is that "healthy", well that depends on your own health and what you are doing; if you are a fitness instructor I'd like to think that your program was healthy. If you are working with toxic materials then the stress from risk of exposure is probably not healthy.
Use time after work and the weekend as a short vacation, and use time between jobs as a longer vacation.
Having been off for 8 months and then jumping into a new job can be tough, you should have made "work search" part of your routine: get up early enough to arrive at the start of work somewhere (that you'd like to work at), travel with the rush hour crowd to determine where you can get to without an unreasonable amount of trouble (some locations are only reached by navigating through several traffic bottlenecks, choose somewhere else), see if you can talk to people going in or on their first break; but be certain to quickly assess if they're receptive to that.
Try to find out the qualifications held by the average employee, and if they have a competent person. Checking online, going in person, and pulling the 'reverse interview' (ask about their qualifications) are good ways to go; frequently places with the lowest pay, worst conditions and least qualified also feature people who think they are doing you a favor and you should have it worse than they did. If the mindset of those you work with isn't normal that's not a place to stay very long.
Always work at places with a positive workplace safety culture and explore how to strengthen organizational culture to be inclusive of safety, otherwise ask for additional payment, performance bonuses and paid time off - there's a balance between which will become important versus what will be paid for to tough it out.
You can think "but then I won't get the job", but you also don't get the stress, low pay, and have to compete with others who disregard their health and safety in order to get ahead (without a realistic material gain).
Some occupations have guidelines from the Occupational Safety and Health Administration:

"Recommended Practices for Safety and Health Programs" (general recommendations)
"Overview: Working in Outdoor and Indoor Heat Environments", recommends acclimatization.
"OSHA Worker Rights and Protections" (know your rights and how to complain)

Remember to eat a good breakfast and catch your breath before heading out, don't run the gauntlet all the way to work.Take your breaks, if your lunch is interrupted you're entitled to restart it; so you know that either won't happen again or it will be an expected part of the job.
Surprises and other people's stress that they try to unload on you can add to your stress, it's difficult to answer is any particular thing stressful when there are additional sources of stress which are not identified by you.
Regularly assess the good and the bad, the rewarding and the stressful. I've worked places where everything had to be one way or another, and the truth is that they could only find a certain number of people who could do that; so always weight how much you dislike with how much you make versus the risk and consequences of losing your job.
If circumstances are not good where you are, it's stressful, and you're not adequately compensated then the next place is pretty much certain to be better. Switch jobs if you must, a lot of places have flexible hours, workweek, duties, everything from come in late to work at home. I'll not get into how bad it was 40 years ago, it's only relevant today as something that people don't want to do.
